# Поиск SourcePort-а, на который приходит запрос, активирующий руткит

Tags: linux

Я не особо силен в Linux, поэтому не уверен в правильности своего вопроса, и уж тем более в том, где искать информацию об этом.

Использую Ubuntu 15.04. Знакомый шутки ради установил мне руткит, я не знаю как его искать, но знаю, что даже после полной переустановки системы (пробовал Ubuntu 14.04 и 16.04), он присылает запрос на конкретный порт для активации руткита. Есть ли возможность задетектить этот порт и как-то остановить его шутки?

Comment: если вы переустановили систему (с пересозданием файловых систем на всех используемых разделах, что производится по умолчанию), то никакого *rootkit-а* у вас нет. // пожалуй, лучшее, что можно почитать по поводу безопасности в операционной системе *gnu/linux*, это: «не предоставляйте злоумышленникам физический доступ к вашему компьютеру».

Comment: второй из ваших вопросов (по поводу «что бы почитать?»), во-первых, не укладывается в тематику сайта, во-вторых, противоречит правилу «для того, чтобы задать ещё один вопрос, используйте кнопку "задать вопрос" в правом верхнем углу страницы». поэтому я его убрал из текста.

Comment: Круто. Наверное что-то вроде [вот этой дряни](http://translate.wooyun.io/2015/10/23/27.html). Рекомендаций в статье я не нашел. Возможно, проще всего отформатировать диск.

Comment: Теоретически может быть даже хуже. При известной сноровке вирус можно прописать в какой-нибудь firmware (например, сетевого адаптера).

Comment: @avp, не пугайте, пожалуйста, новичков, китайскими статьями про засекреченные открытия лаборатории касперского. даже не вдаваясь в возможность существования подобной программы, могу вас заверить, что в конце (нормальной) установки mbr перезаписывается.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но если у ТС эффект в самом деле наблюдается, значит зверь-то где-то живет? Например в биосе. Он же при начальной загрузке всегда используется.

Comment: @avp, автор вопроса даже не написал, что же это такое, в его представлении, — rootkit, и в чем это, с его точки зрения, может проявляться. у меня лично возникают вполне справедливые подозрения, что над автором вопроса просто подшутили. ну, или он нас пытается разыграть.

Comment: Все возможно. Может он просто таким образом хочет пообсуждать тут эту тему, может проверяет нашу компетентность, кто знает?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ничью компетентность я не проверяю. Все что мне этот товарищ рассказал, так это то, что он через разрыв соединения скайпа получает мой прямой IP и отправляет что-то на какой-то конкретной порт. Только что он снова это проделал на абсолютно чистой системе. Единственное, что я не делал, так это полностью не перезаписывал диск нулями.

Comment: Что происходит когда шутник что-то отправит на какой-то порт через скайп? Бегает вокруг, весело размахивая руками, с крикам - Ты видел?, ты это видел как я отправил что-то на какой-то порт через какой-то скайп? Какие ещё иначе проявляет себя этот руткит? Займитесь спортом-мордобоем, чтобы больше никто не смел шутить

Comment: @Sergey шутник получает ко мне root-доступ, после чего обычно создает новую функцию ядра, которая автоматом включает мне Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up каждые 10 минут.
Пожалуйста, перечитайте мой комментарий и вопрос, скайп нужен не для отправки данных, а для получения моего адреса поскольку я сижу за роутером. Весь вопрос в том, **как** узнать порт, на который приходит запрос, и **как** от него избавиться, а не про спорт-мордобой.

Comment: итак, немного определились: раз в десять минут без вашего вмешательства из динамиков, подключенных к звуковой плате компьютера, звучит какая-то мелодия. приложите к вопросу вывод команды `$ ps aux`, выполненной в тот момент, когда мелодия звучит, и через минуту после окончания её звучания. программу skype (и всё прочее, что вы установили) предварительно деинсталлируйте.